# bootstrap выпадающее меню

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

С помощью Bootstrap сделал выпадающее меню, но в `<li>` поставил не ссылки, а `input[type=checkbox]`. Теперь при каждом клике выпадающее меню исчезает. Как его закрепить, чтобы оно не скрывалось пока кликаем по данным checkbox'ам?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn_search_filter" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Где искать?
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu search_filter">
    <li>
      <label for="users">Пользователи</label>
      <input id="users" type="checkbox" name="search_local" class="search_input" value="users" placeholder="Пользователи">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="portfolio">Резюме</label> 
      <input id="portfolio" type="checkbox" name="search_local" class="search_input" value="portfolio" placeholder="Резюме">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="adverts">Объявления</label> 
      <input id="adverts" type="checkbox" name="search_local" class="search_input" value="adverts" placeholder="Объявления">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="vacancies">Вакансии</label> 
      <input id="vacancies" type="checkbox" name="search_local" class="search_input" value="vacancies" placeholder="Вакансии">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, код, который есть у Вас на данный момент.

Comment: добавьте область чекбоксов в исключения, покажите ваш код, добавьте в вопрос [mcve] вашей ошибки

Comment: вот, добавил код

Comment: Вот здесь рабочий код в первом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895806/bootstrap-4-multiselect-dropdown

Comment: @Lenald, честно говоря, я думал, что это встроенный функционал.. Но тоже решение))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать такую структуру:

```
$('.search_filter > li > label').click(function(e) {
    var checkbox = $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]'); // Нашли чекбокс
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));     // Установили атрибут checked в зависимости от текущего значения
    return false;                                            // Сбили клик
});
```

```js
$('.search_filter > li > label').click(function(e) {
    var checkbox = $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]');
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked"));
    return false;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn_search_filter" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Где искать?
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu search_filter">
    <li>
      <label for="users">Пользователи</label>
      <input id="users" type="checkbox" name="search_local" class="search_input" value="users" placeholder="Пользователи">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="portfolio">Резюме</label>
      <input id="portfolio" type="checkbox" name="search_local" class="search_input" value="portfolio" placeholder="Резюме">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="adverts">Объявления</label>
      <input id="adverts" type="checkbox" name="search_local" class="search_input" value="adverts" placeholder="Объявления">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="vacancies">Вакансии</label>
      <input id="vacancies" type="checkbox" name="search_local" class="search_input" value="vacancies" placeholder="Вакансии">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо Вы помогли!

Comment: @АлександрИванов, не за что:)